# Using drag-and-drop reference, moving location of script results in "Unity Text Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, drag-and-drop, object-reference

This simple script works perfectly when it is attached as a component to a Text object and that Text object is dragged to the inspector in Unity's GUI: Text object > script component > field for the public Text.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DisplayReading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textDisplay;

    void Start()
    {
        textDisplay.text = "hi";
    }
}
```

HOWEVER...

If I take `public Text textDisplay` and `textDisplay.text = "hi";` and put them in a script that controls a bunch of buttons on a number panel - a script which is attached to a parent panel - and drag the Text object to the inspector of the Panel, Panel > script component > field for the public Text , I get the error: "Unity Text Object Reference not set to an instance of an object." *Even though the script works.* In other words, it does change the text to display "hi" but gives me an error nevertheless.

So the script works in both cases but in one case it gives me an error. When the script is stand alone, attached to the Text OR to the Panel, and the Text object is dragged and dropped on the stand-alone script component, I get no error. When those two lines of scripting are added to a larger script attached to a Panel and the Text object is dragged and dropped on the Panel's script component, I get an error, although the text does display as desired.

I have tried closing Unity and Visual Studio and restarting. I've tried removing and re-adding the scripts components and the objects to the fields of the components. I did double-check that I am using a Text object, not a TextMeshPro object by mistake. I also tried attaching a stand-alone script to the Panel and dragging the Text object there. That worked with no error. So there is something about either bringing those lines of scripting into a larger script, or something about the drag-and-drop reference when there are a bunch of other objects on the script component that seems to be causing this error.

Any ideas?

In case you're curious about the larger script, here's the beginning. There is no mention of Text or text or any other reference to the Text object in the larger script, except those two lines which I brought over. And yes I did remember to drag and drop the Text Object. Below is a snapshot of my inspector.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using TMPro;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Numpad : MonoBehaviour
{
  
    string[] padnumbers = { "0", "0", "0"};
    string[] combinednum = new string[4];
    string[] displaynum = new string[4];
    bool[] positions = { false, false, false };
    int pos;

    public GameObject B1;
    public GameObject B2;
    public GameObject B3;
    public GameObject B4;
    public GameObject B5;
    public GameObject B6;
    public GameObject B7;
    public GameObject B8;
    public GameObject B9;
    public GameObject Bclear;
    public GameObject B0;
    public GameObject Bdot;
    public GameObject SaveButton;
    public GameObject ManInput;
    public Text textDisplay;

    void Start()
    {
        textDisplay.text = "hi";

        combinednum[0] = padnumbers[0];
        combinednum[1] = padnumbers[1];
        combinednum[2] = ".";
        combinednum[3] = padnumbers[2];
    }
```

...
[image: Unity inspector window snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

Oh I found the problem.

Answer: I had attached another instance of the script to another even higher panel above the immediate parent and then forgot about it. It was that instance of the script that was throwing the error while the other instance of the script was modifying the text as desired.